# Get content from cell without border in word c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, rtf, file-conversion, word-table

I try to get content in cell word in rtf format by using Range.ExportFragment function, but it alway return with border. How to get only content?

I try to use border visible property but when load it to richtextbox, border still display.

```
range.Borders[WdBorderType.wdBorderTop].Visible = false;
range.Borders[WdBorderType.wdBorderBottom].Visible = false;
range.Borders[WdBorderType.wdBorderLeft].Visible = false;
range.Borders[WdBorderType.wdBorderRight].Visible = false;

range.ExportFragment(tempFile, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatRTF);

richtextbox1.Rtf = File.ReadAllText(tempFile);
```

[image]

Comment: If you save a document with a table to RTF (File/SaveAs) is the result the same, or are the borders suppressed by the RTF file converter?

Comment: @CindyMeister i want to get data inside cell of table, i using range propertice to get data and using ExportFragment method to export content of range, but it take all border and content

Comment: Are you saying, then, that you want the text in the table, but no table structures? Should the data be delimited in any way? Have you tried saving as a text file, rather than RTF? It really isn't clear what, exactly, you need...

Comment: Yes, but not only text, this content maybe contain image, or expression ... That's why I have to take RTF instead of text only

Comment: Test this: Select a table then Insert/Table/Table to text to remove the table. If that gives you the kind of result you're looking for you can then loop all tables and use that to remove the table structures...